# how to use a relative path with form API image_button?

Tags: 6, theming

I'm building a module in D6 that renders a form to a custom template (also within the mod).
I need to use an image for the submit button, but I'm having trouble with the path to the image.

```
$form['submit'] = array(
'#type' => 'image_button',
'#src'  => 'sites/all/modules/custom/mymodule/images/show-my-score-button.png',
'#value' => t('Show My Score'),
'#submit' => array('mymodule_submit'),
'#redirect' => '',
```

);

This is the code I have in place, and it is functional. However I can't use the path as it's shown since I don't know where my module will end up.

How can I make the image show in my module while using an image path that is relative to my module?
I'd love to have something like "/images/show-my-score-button.png" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define an absolute path, a relative path won't work. But you can use the [`drupal_get_path()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_path/6) method to retrieve the path to your module, so you don't have to worry about where it will end up in the filesystem.

For example:

```
$image_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/images/show-my-score-button.png';
```